# How to increase the brightness of the badge?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Basically, I have this tab-item with `background-color: #000`
and the badge with `background-color: red`.

I don't like the apparence. 
Indeed, the red is not visible enough.

Is there a way to increase the brightness in css?
Or altering the color with a specific rgb value?

Comment: could try background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);

Comment: Exactly the same result.

Comment: is there any sort of opacity on the element itself?

Comment: choosing another red? one that is more lighter than this one..

Comment: can you give us a full code sample to look at??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the element inspector you'll find that the image is not at full opacity. You should be looking for `opacity: 0.7` (judging by the output red). You can then change it to `opacity: 1`.
This doesn't have to be on the element itself, it can also be on any parent element (in your case likely the bell picture).

Comment: Ok, so if your badge is opacity 1 and it's parent has opacity 0.7, how do you guess that will look? ;)